# How to combine string with the previous one based on condition?

Tags: python, regex, list, text

I have a text file of messages in the form:

```py
with open(code_path) as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
print(contents)

['22/05/2022, 21.58 - Name: message1 \n', 
'22/05/2022, 22.07 – Name2: message2\n', 
'message2 continues\n', 
'22/05/2022, 22.09 – Name: message3\n']
```

Currently I have the messages in strings. Some long messages are split into two. I would like to have a list of the messages in with all messages joined together (starts with the date).

This is what I want:

```py
['22/05/2022, 21.58 - Name: message1 \n', 
'22/05/2022, 22.07 – Name2: message2 + message2 continues\n', 
'22/05/2022, 22.09 – Name: message3\n']
```

Is there a way to do this?

I have found the strings starting with a date with:

```py
import re

dates = [re.findall("^[0-3][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/20[1-2][1-9]", i) for i in contents]
```

But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: What you need is to read the file by line and interate over them, check if it starts with date and if not merge with the previous one. Also depending on the format of your data maybe there is an easier check to do than the date, numbers of ',' for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic approach would be to use a kind of cache: go through the lines,

- if the line starts with a date, append a new item to the cache
- if it doesn't, append to the most recent item.

```py
messages = []
for line in contents:
    if re.match(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4},\s+', line):
        messages.append([line])
    else:
        messages[-1].append(line)
 
# messages
[['22/05/2022, 21.58 - Name: message1 \n'],
 ['22/05/2022, 22.07 – Name2: message2\n', 'message2 continues\n'],
 ['22/05/2022, 22.09 – Name: message3\n']]
```

You could then `join` them (e.g., `[''.join(m) for m in messages]`). Alternatively, it's also possible to build strings directly, but maybe you want to distinguish between primary/following lines at some point, then the list is more useful.

Comment: Hi! Do you know if with `match` the symbol `^` is redundant in the regex? i.e. `r'^\d{2}/...'`

Comment: That's right, `match` matches from the beginning of the string (cf. the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)).

Comment: So, in this case, would it be just redundant, right?

Comment: Yes, it's redundant. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

You might also read all lines, and then match the line starting with a date like pattern followed by all all lines not starting with a date like pattern.

With a more specific date like pattern:

```
import re

with open("file") as f:
    pattern = r"^(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/\d{4},.*(?:\n(?!(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/\d{4},).*)*"
    print(re.findall(pattern, f.read(), re.M))
```

Output

```
[
'22/05/2022, 21.58 - Name: message1 \n', 
'22/05/2022, 22.07 – Name2: message2\n\nmessage2 continues\n', 
'22/05/2022, 22.09 – Name: message3\n'
]
```

---

With a less precise pattern, but a bit shorter:

```
^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4},.*(?:\n(?!\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4},).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string anchor
- `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4},` Match a date like pattern followed by a comma
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4},)`
  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat to match all lines

Example

```
import re

with open("file") as f:
    pattern = r"^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4},.*(?:\n(?!\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4},).*)*"
    print(re.findall(pattern, f.read(), re.M))
```